# avoiding php artisan queue:work : Queue Driver - Redis or Database (Laravel 5.4)

Tags: linux, laravel-5, redis, laravel-5.4, laravel-queue

I am currently using database as my queue driver, I have installed Laravel 5.4 on Windows 10 PC. In order to process queues I have been using `php artisan queue:work` which was completely fine in development stage. Now, the project is completely ready and needs to be deployed on Linux Server (Dedicated) I am not sure how to avoid running command `php artisan queue:work` on terminal in order to process mail jobs?

I have deployed once in shared hosting and I have used cron jobs, But now I have dedicated server I guess I should be able to use something else to run jobs, I was also thinking of using Redis as queue driver rather than database as queue driver

I need some suggestion on what is best. And how to avoid `php artisan queue:work` on dedicated server? Do I need to write small script to make sure jobs run in background as a service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel documentation covers this with supervisor.

See: [Laravel Supervisor configuration](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues#supervisor-configuration)

Supervisor is a process monitor which makes sure your queue command (or any other command for that matter) is executed and restarted if it dies.

### Edit:

See: [Supervisor documentation](http://supervisord.org/)

Basically for centos, you can use yum:

```
yum install supervisor
```

Easy install

```
// required for easy_install (if not installed already)
yum install python-setuptools     
// install supervisor
easy_install supervisor
```

Or pip

```
pip install supervisor
```

After that it's just creating your config (based on the example given on Laravel's documentation), this is handled step by step in:

[Supervisor: creating-a-configuration-file](http://supervisord.org/installing.html#creating-a-configuration-file)

And create the service: [Setup Supervisor](https://rayed.com/wordpress/?p=1496)

After that you can start the service with:

```
service supervisord start
```

Comment: I will look into it. But if you could edit your answer with exact steps? I am using CentOS6 . I am not sure how to proceed with configuration. laravel documentation is quite brief